# Open a pdf file in a webpage(Wordpress) without giving its URL?

Tags: html, wordpress, embed

This problem is a little different, so I will try my best to explain it as much as I can. I would really appreciate any help I can get on this issue.
I have a website where I have a registration form after which the users can view a report. This report is saved on the server and thus people can view it directly as well (by just going to the url of the pdf). I want to find a way such that users have to register in order to view the report. I don't want to use flash as I know mobile browsers have issues with it (Apple). Password protection is also something which I want to avoid. Is there any way where users have to go through the registration in order to view the report? THANKS A LOT

The website is in Wordpress btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this plugin: [**User Access Manager**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-access-manager/)

In that plugin, make a user group and allow access to view your pdf file to that user group only.

This plugin will Redirecting users to other pages if no access.

Try it out. Cheers !!!

Comment: The plugin seems helpful, I will have to play around with it. Thanks for the pointer Libin.

Comment: Welcome buddy. And come back if you have any problems with it.